# Horizontal scrollbar inside bootstrap grid div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ul list which is inside a bootstrap grid element:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="playlist-wrapper">
      <ul id="playlist">
      <li>
      ...
      </li>
       <li>
      ...
      </li>
      <li>
      ...
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If that bunch of li elements are bigger than the col-sm-8's width they will jump to the next line.

I want to add a horizontal scrollbar so all the li elements are in the same li only visible at col-sm-8's width with the possibility to scroll horizontally through them.

I tried setting a fixed height to the wrapper (so only one row can be seen) and adding overflow-y hidden and white-space nowrap but it's not working:

```
#playlist-wrapper{
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow: auto;
    Tried also with overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Also tried:

```
#playlist-wrapper ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Rest of the css not affecting the overflow just to make it a horizontal list and some text/color properties.

```
ul#playlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

ul#playlist li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ul#playlist li p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

With that css I am having a vertical scrollbar. Is it possible to have a horizontal scrollbar somehow?

Comment: Which classes/ids are being affected by your CSS? That seems to be left out in your question.

Comment: Updated with the css ids. All the css mainly affects playlist-wrapper. Tried adding css directly to the ul element but didnt work neither

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://codeply.com/go/IgLjagTmKS

Comment: Yes but I want it to be horizontal scrollbar, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need something like this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      #playlist-wrapper ul li{
        height: 50px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      
      #playlist-wrapper{
        height: 150px;
        width:150px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div id="playlist-wrapper">
          <ul id="playlist">
            <li>Fabian Eduardo Sierra Pineda</li>
            <li>Fabian Eduardo Sierra Pineda</li>
            <li>Fabian Eduardo Sierra Pineda</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```